# Collectstatic configuration error when deploying Django website on to Heroku and S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to deploy my Django website onto Heroku and Amazon S3. However, after I typed `git push heroku master`, I got this:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 298 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput**
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 52.0MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v9
remote:        https://article-django.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/article-django.git
   4514a97..070a1af  master -> master
```

I type in `heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and I get this log:

```
Running `python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` attached to terminal... up, run.4058
/app/static/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/django_test/settings.py", line 142, in <module>
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['article-deanna']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in   __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'article-deanna'
```

'article-deanna' is the name of my `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, as specified in this snippet in settings.py:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except Exception as e:
    print e.message 

if not DEBUG:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['article-deanna']
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['(censored)']
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/' % article-deanna 
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

I also have my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn django_test.wsgi
```

And this snippet of the script `activate`:

```
# added for S3 deployment
export AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=article-deanna
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=(censored)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=(censored)
```

I have the correct `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, so why doesn't Heroku realize that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you has to get the env var from name not from value.

here you set "article-deanna" to the variable **AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME**

`export AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='article-deanna'`

and here you has to get the variable back

`AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I got the error KeyError: 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', so that's not the problem.

Comment: it looks like the variable is not set. Can you try it this way os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'] = "article-deanna"